# Prime number interference patterns

Tags: prime-numbers

Please do excuse this observation, as I am not a mathamatician - just a Scottish Lawyer who (for some mad reason) loves fractals and prime numbers.

Why is it, when I play around with simple images of Ulams Spiral at high resolution on my IPad, I get odd interference pattern. Are the pixels picking up a more hidden pattern? It does not seem to happen with high res random patterns. If you play about with images from the internet, you will see what I mean. I  do hope I am not wasting anyone's time. I love patterns in nature. The undernoted image is of poor quality, but you will get the general idea.

I do apologise as I did not explain myself very well. Also, I only have a rather ancient IPad and live up a mountain with poor signal. In addition, I have no formal training in mathematics - just a rather curious interest. I was googling images of Ulams Spiral, as I was trying to work out why it is that you often get a prime number after a super perfect aliquot number. It is as if nature is saying OK, that last number completely makes sense, lots of divisors, tidy, symmetrical loves itself, even, shapely then.......BANG here is a number which makes no sense at all. No divisors other than 1 and itself. Nature appears to work like this. Anyhow, to get onto my point. If you expand and contract a good quality Ulam Spiral with your finger on the screen, you do get a Moire Pattern (which I think the previous reader is referring to). Now that might be due to how the even numbers relate to the pixels on the screen, but I don't know. Have a look anyway at

http://dmitrybrant.com/images/38m_2318966.png

for instance and expand and contract it. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Maybe you referring to [Moiré patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)? Anyway, this site is about the software Mathematica and I don't think your question is related to this. Maybe this SE site would be more suitable? http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50416/generating-an-ulam-spiral

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  As is Readers will have difficulty understanding what "odd interference pattern" you are asking about.  Was there an image originally provided?  If you use the image uploader it gives an imgur.com link, which can be included in your post, or otherwise you can provide a link to image from the internet.  A Reader can then fix things up to make the image visible in your post.